# Is a relation considered reflexive only if (a, a) ∈ R for every a ∈ M

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Consider the set $M = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and the relation $R = \{(1, 1), (2, 2)\}$. Does this relation satisfy reflexivity with respect to the concept of an "equivalence relation"?

Someone told me that for an relation to satisfy reflexivity, it is not necessary for every element $a ∈ M$ to have $(a, a) ∈ R$, as long as $a$ doesn't appear in any pair in the relation $R$. (i.e. in the above example, since $3$ doesn't appear in any pairs like $(3, 1)$, $(1, 3)$, $(3, 2)$, ...etc. then $(3, 3)$ isn't necessary to belong to $R$) Thus, R above satisfies reflexivity.

However, I don't think that's correct because, as I remember, in order for an relation to satisfy reflexivity, then for every $a ∈ M$, there must be $(a, a) ∈ R$

Comment: A relation $R$ *on $M$* is reflexive if and only if for every $a\in M$, $(a,a)\in R$. You must specify the set on which the relation is considered.

Comment: You are correct, and “someone” is wrong.

Comment: In the definition of an equivalence relation $R$ on $M$, we can replace the assumption that $R$ is reflexive with the assumption that every $x\in M$ is related to another element of $M$.  That's the best interpretation I can give to the unknown _someone_.

Comment: There is not the question of whether or not an equivalence relation satisfies reflexivity: it always do, by definition

Comment: Yes, as Arturo points out, if someone said that the relation would be an equivalence relation on a smaller domain, that would be true.

Comment: @Brian is there a name for that property ($\forall x\in M \exists y \in M$, $x \mathrel{R} y$?) That's a nice little fact.

Comment: @amrsa thanks for the note, I edited the question, I meant to ask if "relation satisfies reflexivity"

Comment: Answering my own question, Wikipedia suggests *serial* or *left-total*; though I'm not sure I like either one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand on the points made in the comments: the reflexive property of a relation does require a “domain” from which the elements come. This is in contrast to the other two properties of an equivalence relation (symmetry and transitivity).

In your example, the relation $R = \{(1,1),(2,2)\}$ is a reflexive relation on $\{1,2\}$, but is not a reflexive relation on $\{1,2,3\}$.

Perhaps of additional note is that there is a notion of a [*quasi-reflexive* relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation#Quasi-reflexivity) on a set, defined by the rule that $(x,y) \in R \implies (x,x),(y,y) \in R$. It is slightly more general in that we only require elements to be related to themselves, if they are related to elements other than themselves. Your example relation would be quasi-reflexive on $\{1,2,3\}$ as a result.